# Problems rotating UIView with drawing inside

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, rotation, drawrect

I want to rotate a UIView with a drawing inside (circle, rectangle or line). The problem is when I rotate the view and refresh the drawing (I need ir when I change some properties of the drawing, i.e) the drawing doesn't follow the view...

**UIView without rotation:**

[image: UIView without rotation]

**UIView with rotation:**

[image: UIView rotated and drawing distortion]

Here is my simple code (little extract from the original code):

Main ViewController

```
class TestRotation: UIViewController {

// MARK: - Properties

var drawingView:DrawingView?

// MARK: - Actions

@IBAction func actionSliderRotation(_ sender: UISlider) {

    let degrees = sender.value
    let radians = CGFloat(degrees * Float.pi / 180)
    drawingView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)

    drawingView?.setNeedsDisplay()
}

// MARK: - Init

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    drawingView = DrawingView(frame:CGRect(x:50, y:50, width: 100, height:75))

    self.view.addSubview(drawingView!)

    drawingView?.setNeedsDisplay() 
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

UIView

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let start = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let end = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width, y: self.frame.size.height)

    drawCicrle(start: start, end: end)
}

func drawCicrle(start:CGPoint, end:CGPoint) {

    //Contexto
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    if context != nil {

        //Ancho
        context!.setLineWidth(2)

        //Color
        context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
        context!.setFillColor(UIColor.orange.cgColor)

        let rect = CGRect(origin: start, size: CGSize(width: end.x-start.x, height: end.y-start.y))

        let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)

        path.lineWidth = 2
        path.fill()
        path.stroke()

    }
}

// MARK: - Init

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

}
```

It seems that the problem is temporally solved if I don't refresh the view after rotating, but if I have to refresh later for some other reason (properties changed), the problem appears again.

What can I do? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `frame` when you should be using the `bounds`.

The `frame` is the rectangle which contains the `view`.  It is specified in the coordinate system of the `superview` of the `view`, and the `frame` changes when you rotate the `view` (because a rotated square extends further in the X and Y directions than a non-rotated square).

The `bounds` is the rectangle which contains the contents of the `view`.  It is specified in the coordinate system of the `view` itself, and it doesn't change as the `view` is rotated or moved.

If you change `frame` to `bounds` in your `draw(_:)` function, it will work as you expect:

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let start = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    let end = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: self.bounds.size.height)

    drawCicrle(start: start, end: end)
}
```

---

Here's a demo showing the oval being redrawn as the slider moves.

[image: Rotate Oval demo]

---

Here's the changed code:

```
class DrawingView: UIView {

    var fillColor = UIColor.orange {
        didSet {
            setNeedsDisplay()
        }
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        let start = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        let end = CGPoint(x: self.bounds.size.width, y: self.bounds.size.height)

        drawCircle(start: start, end: end)
    }

    func drawCircle(start:CGPoint, end:CGPoint) {

        //Contexto
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

        if context != nil {

            //Ancho
            context!.setLineWidth(2)

            //Color
            context!.setStrokeColor(UIColor.black.cgColor)
            context!.setFillColor(fillColor.cgColor)

            let rect = CGRect(origin: start, size: CGSize(width: end.x-start.x, height: end.y-start.y))

            let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)

            path.lineWidth = 2
            path.fill()
            path.stroke()

        }
    }

    // MARK: - Init

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

}
```

---

```
@IBAction func actionSliderRotation(_ sender: UISlider) {

    let degrees = sender.value
    let radians = CGFloat(degrees * Float.pi / 180)
    drawingView?.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)

    drawingView?.fillColor = UIColor(hue: CGFloat(degrees)/360.0, saturation: 1.0, brightness: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have seen your answer after fighting a lot, and before I saw it I discover the issue about rect vs bounds... ;)

Comment: I assumed that the frame height/width was equal to the bounds height/width but this appears to be wrong when rotating. To everyone reading: make sure you replace all your code using `frame` to `bounds` instead!